# How to rearrange virtual desktops in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Is there any solution on how I could rearrange my virtual desktops in the task-view (WIN+TAB)?

Comment: Could `7+ Taskbar Tweaker` help perhaps? Or if not, something similar? That app allows to rearrange taskbar preview windows, something that is non-rearrangeable by default.

Comment: this is the most needed new feature for windows, if they haven't done it yet - I doubt they ever will. Probably they decided it is too confusing for their non-power users

Comment: Didn't there used to be shortcuts to go to a specific desktop? Like Win + Shift + 3. That would certainly help. Doesn't seem to be listed so maybe I'm thinking of something else https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 102):

This is **not possible** in the current version of Windows 10 (20H2) or earlier versions.

However, the recent [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 21337](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/03/17/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21337/) mentions this feature.

We can only hope that this feature will be rolled out to Windows 10 in an upcoming update.

Comment: Your howtogeek.com link seems to indicate that it can and includes a solution.

Comment: @DaveM "please prove a negative"

Comment: Does the latest update have this feature?

Comment: How I hate `micro...`. Desktops can **not **be rearranged, windows placement is **not** saved (place windows to each virtual desktops after restart again and again), windows sizes are **not** saved, desktops are **not** cycled (press 10 time and reach last one) and of course navigation supports only `->` and `<-` **no** up, down or corners. More key strokes, more waste of time. :(

Comment: Will next Windows update (1803 or Redstone 4) have this feature?

Comment: The virtual desktops and the applications residing within them are, of course, available through an API which is significantly inconvenient for most user-focused applications. That said, it should be possible to entirely rearrange a set of applications via this API: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/09/10/virtual-desktop-switching-in-windows-10/

Comment: Can we all give props to this guy for updating this answer for 5 years from 2015?

Comment: Does this work on Windows 11?

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate when you updated the info based on newer Windows' releases. I saw the date of this answer, and wrote it off and expired. As I scrolled something in the comments caught my eye. THEN, I saw a different comment hinting that maybe this answer had been updated. So I looked at the edit date, and edit History!. Only then did I realize that this answer was current and relevant.

Comment: Why remove dates? It is very helpful to indicate a date if you change your answer based on newer releases. I saw the date of this answer, 1st few words, & scrolled, assuming it's outdated. Then, I saw a comment hinting maybe this answer IS up to date. So I looked at the edit date, AND edit History! (hint: It was not a typo fix.) Only then did I realize this answer was current & relevant. It is awesome that the Windows Version number was included! but most of us don't know the version number we're running off the top of our head, & a pain to look up, just to see if we *should* read the answer.

Comment: Was the feature from Insider Build 21337 ever rolled out to a stable build?

Comment: is this still not live?

Answer (score 46):

This is not yet possible on Windows 10, but the best way to encourage the feature change would be to vote for it on Microsoft's Feedback Hub:

https://aka.ms/Kpdo3c (link should open the Feedback Hub)

(at the time of this posting, 2018-02-22, it had 1,188 upvotes)

There are also a few related virtual desktop enhancement requests in there as well. It never hurts to voice what's important to you for a feature.

**Update:** As of the 2018 April Update ("Spring Creators", and introduction of timeline) there is still no way to rearrange the virtual desktops.

**Update:** 2018-07-31, still a no-go, but Feedback Hub now has 1,517 Upvotes for this feature.

**Update:** 2019-07-31, still a no-go for Windows 1809 (Oct 2018 update, aka "Fall Creators, 2018"), but Feedback Hub now has 1,710 Upvotes for this feature.

**Update:** 2020-02-24, I'm currently running the Microsoft insider preview slow-channel and it's still not a feature. This implies it'll be doubtful to see this appear for the "Sprint Creators, 2020" (do they even still call it 'creators update'??)

**Update:** 2021-07-08, I've just installed the Windows 11 Insider Preview and GUESS WHAT?! YOU CAN *FINALLY* REARRANGE THE VIRTUAL DESKTOPS!

Comment: > _Update: 2019-07-31_ welcome back from the future

Comment: Huh, I wonder what date I _actually_ updated it on? ... all the same, it's still not possible on 2019-07-28, so future me is probably still right.

Comment: 2020 version of me looks back on the future-dwelling past-me and confirms that this is indeed still not a feature in Win 10. I'm also running the Windows Insider (slow-channel), so it most likely won't be a feature that exists in spring's 2020 update.

Comment: Did you check the fast ring/developers version?

Comment: Maybe Apple patented rearranging virtual desktops. Let's the only plausible explanation at this point.

Comment: Windows SHOULD also add this to Windows 10. Ridiculous that it's only hoping to be avail in Windows 11, someday. Addresses current customers if you want them to keep coming back. Always they give us more reason to switch OS platforms on our next computer purchase, which also happens way too often.

Answer (score 29):

**A workaround :**

Say you have 6 desktops and you want to switch 2 and 4.

**What do you do ?**

1. You create a 7th desktop, put the content of the 4th into the 7th by moving all windows from the 4th into the 7th, one by one, manually, by hand.
2. Now you move the content of the 2nd into the 4th
3. Finally you move the content of the 7th into the 2nd.

**Enjoy !**

Comment: :facepalm: ‍♂️

Comment: A simple 'swap' implemented with a O(3*n) algorithm. Nice ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can do this (and a lot more) with the following third-party app:
https://github.com/ViRb3/SylphyHornEx

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: This works. It'd be nice if you could do this through by dragging the desktop instead of using shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to this app. The interface is very elegant and it does what it advertises. Since it seems like Microsoft isn't implementing this feature anytime soon, I do think this third-party software is the best way to go for now.

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible in Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 21337:

> #### Reorder and customize your Virtual Desktops
>
> **Reorder Virtual Desktops:**
>
> 1. Enter Task View (via Win + Tab), create multiple new Virtual Desktops.
> 2. Drag and drop a Virtual Desktop to another position in the list in Task View.
> 3. Right click a Virtual Desktop thumbnail in task view and select “Move left” or “Move right” in the context menu to move the desktop to another position.
> 4. Use keyboard navigation to set focus to the desired Virtual Desktop in Task View, and then press ALT + Shift + Left / Right Arrow to move it in either direction in the list.

https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/03/17/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21337/

Comment: But its only available via the "Dev channel", which is especially unstable and not recommended for most people. "There will be some rough edges and low stability".

Comment: Yes, but it will be eventually available in stable channel, so still worth mentioning.

Comment: Curious: anyone know how long on average between availability on a Dev channel and incorporated into regular slow stable updates?  I know there is no way of knowing, and it can vary highly depending on the feature. But for something like this, is it more often a few months, or closer to a year or more?

Comment: "eventually" @Paul ? whens that..

Comment: I guess it was dropped in favor of Win11 sadly @mikew

Comment: do we know for sure that win11 allows reordering?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I currently do...

Dump the following regex tree:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops]
```

The `VirtualDesktopIDs` key will list the current order in which Win10 will recreate the desktops everytime it boots.

The `Desktops` key describes each desktop that's listed in `VirtualDesktopIDs`.

PLEASE NOTE: The `VirtualDesktopIDs` hex data is in reverse (little/bigendin) order from the '{...}' data in the
`VirtualDesktopIDs` keys.

Just reorder the `Desktops` key how you want it, then reorder the `VirtualDesktopIDs` key to match, save, reboot and your virtual desktops should be in your desired order; at least mine do... ;-}

Enjoy!